# Unable to play .wav file from callfire api

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

We are using callfire API for in our Android application(Hybrid application build using sencha and phonegap). The concept of the app is to show the recorded calls in a list and on click of any call in the list it will play the recorded audio file(.wav format). Now the problem is that we are not able to play that file in our Application. We also tried to play that URL directly on Android phone browser but it also didn't worked.

Here is one of the URL of audio file format https://www.callfire.com/cloud/1/files/recording/dynamic/864c81f4a8e6a898042cb47251ca1c85/2012/8/6065312/cid_1319779221_1.wav

When we put this audio file in our server and tried to play it our Application, it worked perfectly.

Can you please tell us what is the reason behind this?

We are using Samsung Galexy Y with software version 2.2 for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML5 audio test available [here](http://www.areweplayingyet.org) to check if it is supported by your device's browser, but it sounds like it is not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're referencing an older version of the CallFire API. There's a new interface coupled with a new API which offers a GetSoundData method. Invoking this method returns raw MP3 data, you can also request WAV.

https://www.callfire.com/api-documentation/version/1.1/CallService/GetSoundData

The documentation offers a PHP example, but the parameters should be the same if you port into another language.

```
<?php
/**
 * You'll need your login/password pair when you create the SOAP client.
 * Don't use the fake login/password provided here; it's just for show and
 * won't work.
 */
$wsdl = "http://callfire.com/api/1.1/wsdl/callfire-service-http-soap12.wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'login'        => 'YourLoginId',    
    'password'     => 'YourPassword'));
/**
 * GetSoundData. Get raw binary sound data (MP3 or WAV) for stored sound asset.
 */
$request = new stdclass();
$request->Id = 9; // long required  
$request->Format = 'MP3'; // SoundFormat   [WAV, MP3]
$response = $client->GetSoundData($request);
$byteCount = file_put_contents("my_returned_sound.mp3", $response);
echo "byteCount: " . $byteCount;
// Sample response:
// byteCount: 22749
?>
```